# Can I nest templates?

Tags: c++

I want to do the following:

`QThreadStorage<QSharedPointer<sqlite3>> database;`

but the editor is reporting a syntax error. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that >> at the and of your expression is parsed as a bit-shift operator instead of end of template. It was fixed in c++11 but in previous versions of c++ you need to add a space between angle brackets : `QThreadStorage<QSharedPointer<sqlite3> > database;`

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is interpreted as an operator rather than nested generics in pre-C++11.

You'll need to upgrade your compiler, or just leave a space between them, like `> >`.